# Execute an MSBuild target only once per a solution build

Tags: msbuild

Given a Visual Studio solution composed of arbitrary number of projects all sharing a *Directory.Build.targets* file with a target called *PrintEnvVars*.

How could I ensure that the target *PrintEnvVars* gets called only once per entire solution build? Preferably during the build of the first project of the solution (in the project build order).

Comment: You can use [`Condition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-element-msbuild?view=vs-2017) and [`property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-element-msbuild?view=vs-2017) element. I can't start `callTarget`, but I can run `Exec` only once for the entire solution. So if your `PrintEnvVars` is actually a script, I can suggest a solution.

Comment: How could you run a script once per a solution? That would actually help.

Comment: I assume there's a reason why you cannot write a script that prints the environment variables and *then* build the solution?